# Finding Variables - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner Javascript uni student, and I'm having some difficulty getting the answer for one part of the question below.

> Trace the following JavaScript code, and write the final values of the
>   variables (`x`, `y`, `z`, `w`).   Show your working.
>
> ```
> function hot(a, b, c) {
>   if (a == b) {
>     return (c + b);
>   }
>   else if (a > b) {
>     return (c + c);
>   }
>   else {
>     return cold(b);
>   }
> }
>
>
> function cold(a) {
>   var ans = a;
>   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
>     ans = ans + a;
>   }
>   return ans;
> }
>
>
> var x = 10;
> var y = 3;
> x = x + 8;
> var z = hot(x, y, x);
> var w = 2;
> w = hot(w, z, x);
> y = y + “5”;
> ```

I worked out that `x = 18`, `y = "35"`, `z = 36`.
**W is what is stumping me** I know it `= 144`, I'm just not sure how.
If someone could please explain what happens when it runs through the cold function.

Comment: Open up the JS console in your browser and put breakpoints in the code. Step through the lines and watch the values of the variables change.

Comment: Or rather, put *one* breakpoint at the `hot(w, z, x)` call and then repeatedly press *Step into*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get `x= 10+8= 18.`

Then you'll get `z=hot(18,3,18)`

so z will become 36 because 'a' which is 18 > 'b' which is 3.

So it returns `c + c` which is 18+18 = 36.

Further `w=hot(2,36,18)`

Here a isnt equal to c and a isn't greater than b. So it enters cold(b) which means cold(36)

Here `ans=36`

It'll enter the for loop 3 times.

Hence ans=a+ans

Since ans was already 36, you'll add 36, 3 more times to it making it 144

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in detail, I understand where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When the cold function runs it takes `a`, assigns it to the variable `ans` and then initiates a `for` loop that runs whilst `0 <= i < 3`, adding `a` to `ans` each time.

So if the loop variable `i` starts on 0, runs once (`ans + a`), then once again for `i=1` (`ans + a + a`) and `i=2` (`ans + a + a + a`). So the function returns `4a`

```
cold(2)

var ans = 2;

i = 0, 0 < 3, therefore ans = 2 + 2
i = 1, 1 < 3, therefore ans = 2 + 2 + 2
i = 2, 2 < 3, therefore ans = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2
i = 3, 3 = 3, therefore loop ends

2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 4(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this is detail, I really need someone to break it down.